# Slow Bounce Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to use easing and make an image go up and down slowly. I got it working, but there's a "skip" in the first loop. You can see it in action at https://culturehog.com and here's my code:

```
// Bounce

function pushDavidUp() {
  $("#david").css({
    'transition' : 'transform 5s ease-in-out 0s',
    'transform' : 'translateY(-50px)'
  });
  setInterval(pushDavidDown, 5000);
}
function pushDavidDown() {
  $("#david").css({
    'transition' : 'transform 5s ease-in-out 0s',
    'transform' : 'translateY(50px)'
  });
  setInterval(pushDavidUp, 5000);
};
pushDavidDown();
```

I suspect it's something in the way I'm applying the CSS, but was wondering if I could compensate with the JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with CSS `keyframes`. Make sure to add respective vendor prefixes. See the code below:

```css
.container{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.david{
    animation: upDown 5s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
    transform : translateY(0px)
}

@keyframes upDown{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="david" src="https://culturehog.com/images/david.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `setInterval()` because it will call the method you pass as argument every `N` milliseconds (in your case `5000`), so you will end with multiple calls to the same function after some time. A solution to this will be using a listener on the event `transitionend` to call your functions each other, like this:

```js
function pushDavidUp()
{
  $("#david").css({
    'transition' : 'transform 5s ease-in-out 0s',
    'transform' : 'translateY(-50px)'
  });
  
  $("#david").one(
    'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
    pushDavidDown
  );
}

function pushDavidDown()
{
  $("#david").css({
    'transition' : 'transform 5s ease-in-out 0s',
    'transform' : 'translateY(50px)'
  });

  $("#david").one(
    'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
    pushDavidUp
  );
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    pushDavidDown();
});
```

```css
#david {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="david">DAVID</div>
```